# What's the purpose of the following two versions of constructors?

Tags: javascript

Reading some code, every class has two versions of constructors, Capital Letter and Small Letter.
I don't know why need to write like that?

Version 1

```
  T.A = function (x) {      
       };
```

Version 2

```
T.a = function (x) { 
        if (!x || x instanceof T.A ) {
            return x;
        }
        return new T.A(x);
    };
```

Comment: I have no idea why that's like that, but JavaScript doesn't have classes, only objects.

Comment: I dont think that is a common structure, what is your source?

Comment: `T` is some object; `a` and `A` are properties on `T`; `a` appears to be a simple function but `A` is a "class".  It's just an empty constructor.  `a` looks like a factory function.

Comment: Having both isn't required, in general. It would be a practice / design decision for the particular application. The 2nd also likely isn't used as a constructor; just as a regular function that may return a `new` instance of the 1st, pending certain conditions.

Comment: Is there a typo? It's not `if( !x || this instanceof T.A )`?

Comment: The second form is odd. Normally, if I saw something like that, I would expect `this` to be used instead of a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalizing the first letter of a constructor function is a JavaScript naming convention adopted to tell developers that the function needs to be called with new. This matters because JavaScript doesn't have classes, but has functions that can act like standard OO constructors.